# stand your way; stand in your way

Tags: prepositions, adjuncts

> (I don't want to?) stand your way

I think I might be remembering what I'd heard on the educational local radio while driving, but those three words are all I can remember. When I heard them, ‘*your way*’ would be a locative adjunct I thought, and the phrase means that somebody, maybe I, is in the place of blocking you. But it seems, looking up dictionaries, that the phrase needs ‘*in*’ before ‘*your way*.’ Can the phrase use without ‘*in*’? Or must I just have heard wrong?

Comment: Might you have heard "stand your ground?"  (Meaning _don't change your mind/give in to pressure in the face of opposition._)  I don't know what "stand your way" would mean.  (Or maybe you heard "have your way" meaning get to do what you want to do, or have someone else do as you want them to.)

Comment: this phrase without 'in' sounds unnatural and incorrect. So its likely that you mighe have misheard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to block your way.

I don't want to stand in your way.

I don't want to be in your way.

Scram, cat! You're in my way!

All of the above mean that something or something is impeding one's progress or movement.